# "Role" does not exists in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have been reading [this tutorial](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#add-pgrouting-functions-to-database). There is the below command to login as a user:

```
# login as user "user"
psql -U user
```

when I execute the above command, I get an error saying the following:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist
```

The only help I saw online was [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL#FATAL:__role_.22myusername.22_does_not_exist), the have said the following:

> **FATAL: role "myusername" does not exist**
>
> By default PostgreSQL connects to the PostgreSQL user with the same
>   name as the current unix user. You have not created a PostgreSQL user
>   by that name in your database.
>
> Create a suitable user, or specify a different username to connect
>   with. In the command line tools the -U flag does this.

But I still don't quite understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: You get the error because you have not created a user with the name `user`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have first to login in a linux shell as the user `postgres` and than create new postgres user with the command `createuser`. The system user `postgres` is created automatically by the Postgres installer.

Execute this code in the console (change `your_username` with a username of your choice):

```
sudo -u postgres -i
createuser -l -d -P your_username
```

Better you create a database with the same name too (this makes the login later easier):

```
createdb your_username -O your_username
```

Then you should be able to connect in psql with

```
psql -h localhost -U your_username
```

Answer (score 8):

Please check to see if the user exists.

```
\dg
```

If not, you need what is missing in the tutorial and you edit it if necessary.

```
CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD '<here you password>';
```